# Is there is a need to continously send command via DSHOT protocol?

Tags: esc, dshot, esc-protocol

I am building a flight controller and was implementing the Dshot protocol for esc communication. What I could not find is that if you need to send the data frame continuously to the esc. Because when I am not sending it continuously the motor just stop spinning, is this the way it is, or maybe it depends on esc to esc and the firmware installed on the esc?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with DSHOT specifically (hence a comment), but a number of RC protocols use continuous commands to show an active RF link; the assumption is that if the commands stop, the link is down and aircraft should enter it's 'fail safe' mode. You haven't specific the type of ESC in use, but for fixed wing RC aircraft this is often to stop the motor and centre the control surfaces so that it can glide down and limit flyaway range, which could explain the behaviour here. There may be a setting to instead hold the last power level commanded, but you would have to check your ESC manual.

Comment: @Kralc Thank you for your response, it is a low-cost esc bought on Aliexpress, so I can imagine that a lot of proprieties are not implemented, just the DSHOT throttle command, for example, I can't even implement spin change direction via esc command: I had to manually exchange the wires. I appreciate your answer on RC protocols, which may also explain the behavior of the esc I am using.